# Where/how can I find a complete list of debug flags for sendmail 8.14.4?

Tags: centos, sendmail

CentOS 5.9 | SendMail 8.14.4

I recently learned about debug flags in sendmail and would like to keep a list of them for my specific version (8.14.4).  I understand that these debug flags change/grow from version to version so I'll need to look them up on my specific server for an accurate/complete listing.

How can I do this? From what I can gather online, I may need to review the code and the `TRACEFLAGS` file?

Can someone elaborate on the steps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the best list *with descriptions* is provided by *The Bat Book* - [Sendmail 4th edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596510299.do). It covers Sendmail versions 8.10-8.14. It was released in 2007.

Do not expect to get **full** list. e.g. 3rd edition provides no details about -d17 (MX tracking).

Anyway IMHO *The Bat Book* is handy anyway for detailed *advanced* level Sendmail knowledge.

[Sendmail -d switches list at etutorials.org](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Sendmail/Part+II+Administration/Chapter+16.+Debug+sendmail+with+-d/16.4+Table+of+All+-d+Categories/)